# How research for a file in file system

Tags: .net, xml, filesystems

I'm developping a web application with .NET. I store files(file system). How can I research for a file? I'm thinking to create an XML file for each file stored. Is this the best way to do research? is there an algorithm to research without looking over all xml files?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

where :

```
@"c:\MyDir\" => start directory 
"*.bmp" => filter of files, can be anything using wildcards 
SearchOption.AllDirectories => search through all subdirectory tree
```

to search for all files containing some specified text use [FindInFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127982.aspx).

Comment: no... it returns an array of strings containing the name of files with full paths found in all subdirectories of c:\MyDir\

Comment: And how to search the file which contain a text?